# How can I read a custom section within the loader?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, elf

I'm trying to embed information (a simple integer) inside the executable object file (Elf) of a process in Linux.

I've accomplished that by writing the integer value as binary inside a file, and then by copying the binary file content using the objcopy command.

```
objcopy --add-section .customsection=binaryfile processElfFile newProcessElfFile
```

In this way, inside newProcessElfFile I have a perfectly working copy of the process with a new section containing the integer value, and I can see the section by using

```
readelf -e newProcessElfFile
```

I have also verified the section value being correct by using some C code on top of the Libelf library. Everything works fine.

Now, I want to read the integer value contained in the new section and perform a printk when the elf file is loaded to be executed.

In order to achieve this, I need to modify the loader code, which is kernel side.

The problem now is that:

- I cannot write code inside the kernel which uses the libelf library, so I cannot access directly the section value as I do with my user-side program.
- The elf kernel loader, contained inside linux-VERSION/fs/binfmt_elf.c, in the function load_elf_binary(), doesn't read elf sections, but access the elf program headers, which point towards elf segments, not the single sections.

In order to solve the problem I guess I need to link my custom section within a segment such that I can access it.

So I have 2 related questions:

- Can I somehow read directly my custom section within the loader?
- If not, How can I make a segment link to the custom section, so that I can access it using the elf file program headers?

Another possibility may be to add the integer value as an element of the already existent .rodata section, but I unfortunately don't know how to perform it and again how to access that section in the kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ELF header (`Elf32_Ehdr` or `Elf64_Ehdr`) contains information pointing to the section header table (members `e_shoff`, `e_shentsize`).  Together with the section string table index (`e_shstrndx`), this information can be used to read the section headers and eventually locate the data you are interested in.

Comment: Note however that (unlike segments) sections headers are *not* required at execution time, and will be missing from fully-stripped binaries (this is why the kernel only uses segments).

Comment: Thank you, I have used those informations and succeeded at reading the elf binary file by modifying the load_elf_binary() kernel function

Comment: @AndreaB I am trying to do the same thing and having issues with viewing the new section (readelf -e). Where does it appear for you?

Comment: @AndreaB Rather, I do see the new section appear but I don't see it in the "Section to Segment mapping: Segment Sections..." portion